# Not a valid Identifier T SQL Dynamic SQL inside a CTE

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, common-table-expression, dynamic-sql

Working on a stored procedure that stored it's results in a temp table and wanted to convert to a CTE.

Code :

```
DECLARE  @SQL nVARCHAR(max)

SET @SQL = '
;with CTE_RESULT 
(
        CAMP_ABBR,
        ORIG_CALL_DATE,
        DONOR_ID,
        ACCOUNT_NUMBER_100,
        COMPANY_NAME_100,
        FIRST_NAME,
        LAST_NAME,
        PHONE,
        STREET1,
        STREET2,
        STATE,
        CITY,
        ZIP_CODE,
        WAVE_NAME,
        EMAIL,
        ORIGINAL_EMAIL,
        CODE1,
        DISPOSITION_CODE,
        DESCRIPTION 
)AS

(
SELECT  CAMP_ABBR,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR,ORIG_CALL_DATE,101),
        DONOR_ID,
        ACCOUNT_NUMBER_100 AS ACCOUNT_ID,
        COMPANY_NAME_100,
        FIRST_NAME,
        LAST_NAME,
        TEL_AREA_CODE + TEL_PREFIX + TEL_ROOT AS PHONE,
        STREET1,
        STREET2,
        STATE,
        CITY,
        ZIP_CODE,
        WAVE_NAME,
        EMAIL,
        ORIGINAL_EMAIL,
        CODE1,
        R.DISPOSITION_CODE,
        D.DESCRIPTION 
FROM placeholder1 t1
WHERE COLUMN IN(''01'',''02''))
'

EXEC @SQL
```

Returns the following error:

> Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 114
>   The name ' ;with CTE_RESULT (CAMP_ABBR, ORIG_CALL_DATE, DONOR_ID, ACCOUNT_NUMBER_100, COMPANY_NAME_100, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE, STREET1, STREET2, STATE, CITY, ZIP_CODE, WAVE_NAME, EMAIL, ORIGINAL_EMAIL, CODE1, DISPOSITION_CODE, DESCRIPTION) AS
>
> ( SELECT  CAMP_ABBR,      CONVERT(VARCHAR,ORIG_CALL_DATE,101),        DONOR_ID,
>         ACCOUNT_NUMBER_100 AS ACCOUNT_ID,       COMPANY_NAME_100,       FIRST_NAME,
>         LAST_NAME,      TEL_AREA_CODE + TEL_PREFIX + TEL_ROOT AS PHONE,
>         STREET1,        STREET2,        STATE,      CITY,       ZIP_CODE,       WAVE_NAME,
>         EMAIL,      ORIGINAL_EMAIL,         CODE1,      DISPOSITIO'
>   is not a valid identifier.

Looks like it's reaching varchar limit for the local variable but I have no idea what the cause is.

Comment: you've got "R.DISPOSITION_CODE" and "D.DESCRIPTION" in your select clause, but no tables are aliased 'r' or 'd'

Comment: From what you posted there is no reason for dynamic sql in the first place. It is just making this more complicated.

Comment: Greenspark they're aliased just not all the code is here the code works on it's own outside of the CTE I'm doing this so I know how to.

Comment: @CMO79 Your code has plenty mistakes.

Comment: you've defined the CTE but you havent selected anything from it.. you basically did   `with cte as (select a from table)`.. you need to use the cte like `with cte as (select a from table) select * from cte`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move `AS` keyword closer to `WITH` and you need to reformat the query similarly to this:

```
;with CTE_RESULT AS -- NOTE: AS moved here
(
    SELECT
        CAMP_ABBR,
        ORIG_CALL_DATE,
        DONOR_ID,
        ACCOUNT_NUMBER_100,
        COMPANY_NAME_100,
        FIRST_NAME,
        LAST_NAME,
        PHONE,
        STREET1,
        STREET2,
        STATE,
        CITY,
        ZIP_CODE,
        WAVE_NAME,
        EMAIL,
        ORIGINAL_EMAIL,
        CODE1,
        DISPOSITION_CODE,
        DESCRIPTION
    FROM placeholder1 t1
    WHERE COLUMN IN(''01'',''02'')
) -- AS -- this AS here should be causing the error.
SELECT * FROM CTE_RESULT
```

Read more about Common Table Expressions syntax here: [WITH common_table_expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql).

Comment: Promising but after removing initial AS and moving up. Getting a syntax error now. for the first field camp_abbr.

Comment: @CMO79 yes, because you need to rewrite the whole thing. Notice, you declare `CTE_RESULT` but never `JOIN` or `SELECT` from it.

Comment: thats what i needed to realize. Should be enough to fix syntax i'm good with that answer. Thanks!

Comment: @CMO79 I've updated the query with the proposed format. See if you can fit it completely in your context.

Answer (score 4):

`EXEC @SQL` should be `EXEC (@SQL);` first one gives me the is not a valid identifier.

Thanks

Comment: Or better yet use exec sp_executesql @SQL

Comment: I've tried both and then get an incorrect syntax error near ')'

Comment: Check for unnecessary ( and ) in the SELECT statement?

Answer (score 0):

Was executing the local variable but did not select from the CTE fixed by selecting from the CTE that was populated in the local variable. :

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME,
        @ENDDATE DATETIME,
        @SQL nVARCHAR(max)

SET @SQL = '
;with CTE_RESULT  
(
        CAMP_ABBR,
        ORIG_CALL_DATE,
        DONOR_ID,
        ACCOUNT_NUMBER_100,
        COMPANY_NAME_100,
        FIRST_NAME,
        LAST_NAME,
        PHONE,
        STREET1,
        STREET2,
        STATE,
        CITY,
        ZIP_CODE,
        WAVE_NAME,
        EMAIL,
        ORIGINAL_EMAIL,
        CODE1,
        DISPOSITION_CODE,
        DESCRIPTION 
)
AS
(
SELECT  M.CAMP_ABBR,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR,ORIG_CALL_DATE,101),
        DONOR_ID,
        ACCOUNT_NUMBER_100 AS ACCOUNT_ID,
        COMPANY_NAME_100,
        FIRST_NAME,
        LAST_NAME,
        TEL_AREA_CODE + TEL_PREFIX + TEL_ROOT AS PHONE,
        STREET1,
        STREET2,
        STATE,
        CITY,
        ZIP_CODE,
        WAVE_NAME,
        EMAIL,
        ORIGINAL_EMAIL,
        CODE1,
        R.DISPOSITION_CODE,
        D.DESCRIPTION 
FROM CMSPRD18.CAMP.DBO.GHIL0001_MAS M
LEFT JOIN CMSPRD18.CAMP.DBO.GHIL0001_RES R
ON M.UNIQUE_NUMBER = R.UNIQUE_NUMBER
JOIN [ADMIN].[DBO].[CAMPAIGN] C 
ON M.CAMP_ABBR = C.CAMP_ABBR
JOIN [ADMIN].[DBO].DISPOSITION D 
ON C.CAMP_ID = D.CAMP_ID
AND R.DISPOSITION_CODE = D.DISPOSITION_CODE
WHERE R.DISPOSITION_CODE IN(''01'',''02''))

SELECT * 
FROM CTE_RESULT

'
```

EXEC (@SQL)

This was what I was wantingto achieve with the conversion.